# DesignTime Error Wpf ValidatesOnTargetUpdated NullReferenceException

Tags: wpf, data-binding, validationrules, xaml-designer

I have the same question as in the link below, but the answers where not satisfying for me.

[ValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated NullReferenceException at Design Time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45708488/12474837)

**XAML**

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox">
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="MyText">
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(MyTextBox, TextBox.TextProperty);
     binding?.ValidationRules.Add(new MyValidationRule()
      {
        ValidatesOnTargetUpdated = true
      });
```

It works with this section in code behind. But I am looking for a only XAML solution, because it is more intuitive and for me better maintainable. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a "solution" (or more a workaround) on my own. The designer works for me if I change ValidatesOnTargetUpdated to ValidationStep with the wished value.

Attention: For example, the TextBox behaves differently if you put in ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" and ValidationStep="ConvertedProposedValue". More information on [ValidationRule with ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" is called with BindingExpression instead of updated value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342715/validationrule-with-validationstep-updatedvalue-is-called-with-bindingexpressi).

However, I could not find why ValidatesOnTargetUpdated did not work.